# Modelica Coding Standards / Modelica When Statement

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Greeting Everyone,

Happy New Year 2020

I am using Openmodelica 1.14 release version on 64 bit windows 7 system.

I am facing some trouble with ‘when’ statement in OMSimulator. While searching for solution, I came across a [closed ticket #2664 in Openmodelica](https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/2664). I can still see the reported issue in the current release version of Openmodelica.

I am including the relevant files of ticket # 2664.

```
model SimpleTest "just a simple model - Compilation etc."
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.IntegerInput u annotation(Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-100, 40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-80, 40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.IntegerOutput y annotation(Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {100, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {100, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
algorithm
  when change(u) then
    y := y + 2;
  end when;
  annotation(Icon(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, preserveAspectRatio = true, initialScale = 0.1, grid = {2, 2})), Diagram(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, preserveAspectRatio = true, initialScale = 0.1, grid = {2, 2}), graphics = {Rectangle(origin = {-6.15, 2.93}, fillColor = {0, 133, 199}, fillPattern = FillPattern.HorizontalCylinder, extent = {{-77.89, 83.75}, {88.14, -92.53}})}));
end SimpleTest;
```

Is `SimpleTest.mo` as per Modelica standards?

While compilation of `SimpleTest.mo` , it throws a Translation Warning

```
Assuming fixed start value for the following 1 variables:
         y:DISCRETE(flow=false fixed = false ) SimpleTest type: Integer
```

How to avoid this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a warning. When you define a discrete variable like this such that it depends on it's previous value in a when condition, it has to have a fixed start value. Just providing a start value kind of is a guess value for the compiler, when you fix it you tell the compiler that it has to use this value for the initialization.

If you don't provide a start value it is set to zero, if you don't fix it, the compiler fixes it automatically (resulting in the warning).

Simple example:

```
Integer y(start=0, fixed=true);
```

Applied on your model:

```
model SimpleTest "just a simple model - Compilation etc."
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.IntegerInput u annotation(Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-100, 40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-80, 40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.IntegerOutput y(start=0, fixed=true) annotation(Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {100, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {100, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
algorithm
  when change(u) then
    y := y + 2;
  end when;
  annotation(Icon(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, preserveAspectRatio = true, initialScale = 0.1, grid = {2, 2})), Diagram(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, preserveAspectRatio = true, initialScale = 0.1, grid = {2, 2}), graphics = {Rectangle(origin = {-6.15, 2.93}, fillColor = {0, 133, 199}, fillPattern = FillPattern.HorizontalCylinder, extent = {{-77.89, 83.75}, {88.14, -92.53}})}));
end SimpleTest;
```

Comment: `y(start=0, fixed=true)`  eliminates the translation warning. Is when statement  `y := y + 2` a valid modelica code?

Comment: A sorry, i missed your actual point here. Inside an actual algorithm it is, if it was in an equation you would need to state `y = pre(y) + 2`.

Comment: Just as a small clarification: Inside an algorithm only assignments are allowed, that works just as in regular programming languages. Equatiions on the other hand can be rearranged, therefore `y = y + 2` would not be valid as it states that `0=2` which can never be true. You can formulate `when` and `ìf` statements in equations and if you do so you need to respect that. The `pre` operator uses the left limit value, the value of the last time step.  In general i would prefer using equations as much as possible but avoid `pre` as much as possible.